How to change the access type of a Google Meet from Trusted to Open
I have a calender with thousands of events which need to be set to open to allow all guests to enter without being "let in"
I know this is a strange and niche scenario, but basically I have a huge number of calendar events which need to be set to "Open". The guests for these events have provided email addresses which are not gmail accounts, so cannot enter the meet without being let in.
The calendar events were created with the following method:
...
    var resource = {
      'start': { 'dateTime': startTime },
      'end': { 'dateTime': endTime },
      'anyoneCanAddSelf': true,
      'attendees':[{'email':"guestemail"}],
      'conferenceData': {
          'createRequest': {
              'conferenceSolutionKey': { 'type': "hangoutsMeet" },
            'requestId': request_id
          },
      },
      'summary': room_name
    };

    Calendar.Events.insert(resource, calendarId, {
    "conferenceDataVersion": 1});
...

It is possible to change the meet access settings to "Open", but each individual event needs to be edited, which I would definitely prefer to avoid, because there are truly thousands of these events. I have poured through the documentation and have been unable to find any mention of this, other than going into the admin console and changing the entire calendar's security settings, which isn't possible as I am not the administrator, and it would likely be a bad idea to change everything for this one project. Is there something I am missing in the creation process, or is there some way to access the events and change the settings without manually clicking through the settings? Something along the lines of:
  var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end);

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
    var event = events[i];
    event.setAccessType("open");


Take a look at the Google Meet API
